# Update Ajax url after retrywhen

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

In retrywhen, i able to re-execute http request upon failure just like example at [RxJs Observables: run retryWhen after some more async requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40906748/rxjs-observables-run-retrywhen-after-some-more-async-requests/40918207#40918207). I would like ajax(..) to re-input new option once it fails. Let say I would like to change header or url after first time http request fail. Any example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All what `retryWhen` does is that it re-subscribes to its source Observable. What this means is up to you.

For example you can use `Observable.defer()` to return a different Observable on every re-subscription:

```
let retries = 0;

Observable.defer(() => {
    if (retries++ === 3) {
      return Observable.of('whatever');
    }
    return this.http.get(...);
  })
  .retryWhen((errors: Observable) => errors)
  .subscribe(...);
```

Similarly you could use for example `Observable.create()`.